# Need Help Writing Some Simple Conditional ASP Code

Tags: asp.net, webforms

The following code renders a textbox inside of a column and fills the textbox with the value of a `DESCRIPTION` field:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Notes.LBL_LIST_DESCRIPTION" SortExpression="DESCRIPTION" ItemStyle-Width="20%" >
        <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DESCRIPTION" BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="none" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="dataField" Text='<%# Eval("DESCRIPTION") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Width="200px" TabIndex="11" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn >
```

I want to append the description with the text "[DELETED]" in red if the value of the field `DELETED` (a bit field) equals `1`.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of appending, I just added a span:

```
<%# Sql.ToInteger(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DELETED")) == 1 ? "<span style='color: red;'>[Deleted]</span>" : "" %>
```